# Bootstrap switch working with only one state

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

I am using the Bootstrap Switch library but after writing the following code, I'm able to pass only the 'True/Yes/on' value to the backend. The other state is not being passed at all.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="anonymous" checked>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
   $("[name='anonymous']").bootstrapSwitch({
       state:false,
       size:'mini',
       onText:'Yes',
       offText:'No',
       offColor:'primary',
       onColor:'danger'
   });
</script>
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Remove `,` comma from after last option.

Answer (score 1):

Your example isn't 100% clear enough to illustrate  what the potential problem could be, but `state` should return the correct element state.

```
$("[name='anonymous']").on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
    console.log(state);
});
```

The code you provided only instantiates the element, you need to make use of the change event / make sure you read the new value on whatever submit function you're using.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cu5ar6go/)